# Making php generated image be seen as a file

Tags: php, image, file

I have this code to show images stored outside the public web folders.

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($iddb, "SELECT url, extension FROM imagenes WHERE id=$id");
if ($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_BOTH))
    {   
        $ruta_archivo = $row2['url'];
        $extension =$row2['extension'];
        $filePath=$ruta_outside.$ruta_archivo;
        {
            $image = file_get_contents($filePath);
        }   
    }
header('Content-Type: image/.$extension.');
echo $image;
```

I can call it in an html tag as follows and it works.

```
<img src='http://my_domain.com/content_image.php?id=11' height='40' width='40'/>
```

However when I share my pages in facebook, it can't be located as an image.  I used the og: tag but that address it's not being recognized as an image.

Do you have an idea hoy to give the info to the client, so it understands it as an url ended with a file name? like

```
http://my_domain.com/imagenid11.jpg
```

Thanks

Comment: Your header is literally "Content-Type: image/.$extension.", which is not a valid content type. You're using single quoted strings and/or string concatenation wrong.

Comment: try `header('Content-Type: image/'.$extension);`

Comment: That's not the issue, the images are being recognized by <img> tag, but thanks for the recommendation. The parser actually understands that format, even it's not standard. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is url rewriting. Make use of the apache extension mod_rewrite if you're using Apache. If you're using nginx, use rewrite.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

And you should change `header('Content-Type: image/.$extension.');` to `header('Content-Type: image/'.$extension);`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know if I can change the apache files on the hosting server, but I'll find out.  And BTW, php parse accepts the string as I wrote it header('Content-Type: image/.$extension.');  The images are showing in the <img> tag. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Variables in single quotes DON'T get parsed.

Comment: Yes, they do, and please don't shout. Test the code by yourself.

Comment: Read the note in the php manual. `Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.`

Comment: What you're actually telling the browser is `Content-Type: image/.$extension.`

Comment: Well, I used wireshark to capture the download and you are right, it's not being expanded.  I thought it was because the image is shown in the browser anyways. Thanks for you help.